# How's the chain rule applied?

Tags: calculus, differential

When developing Lagrangian formalism, it is essential to set generalized coordinates:

$ x_{i} = x_{i}(q_{j},t)$ where $t$ is time. $q$ is the generalized cooridnate we wish to use.

During derivation, we have to calculate this:

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial x_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}= \sum_{k}\frac{\partial^2 x_{i}}{\partial q_{k}\partial q_{j}}\dot{q}_{k} + \frac{\partial^2 x_{i}}{\partial q_{j}\partial t}$

Where $\dot{q} = \frac{dq}{dt}$

Not too sure why chain rule is applied in this case, but I'm guessing it's because of:

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial x_{i}}{\partial q_{j}} =  \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial x_{i}(q_{j},t)}{\partial q_{j}}$

But I'm not too sure how that expands into the expression given above.

Comment: $x_i$ depends on $q_j$ and $t$ only, it does not depend on, say, $q_k$ ($k\not = j$) Then how come that the sum ($$\sum_{k}\frac{\partial^2 x_{i}}{\partial q_{k}\partial q_{j}}\dot{q}_{k}$$)does not contain only one element? Namely $\frac{\partial^2 x_i}{\partial q_j^2}\frac{d q_j}{d t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule for a 2 variable function $f(x(t),y(t))$ is
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

If your function $x$ depends on $q_1,q_2,...,q_n$ and $t$, then we generalize the above formula to include all the $q_k$'s. Let's say we want to find $\frac{d x}{dt}$:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_1}\frac{dq_1}{dt}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_2}\frac{dq_2}{dt} +\cdots +\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_n}\frac{dq_n}{dt}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$$

Doing the same thing for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_j}$ will give you the formula you have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: fantastic answer! I just got it myself, but your answer is perfect.